# How to resolve ambigious colum after join in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

When I join two tables (objects) using statement as

```
session.query(object, robject).filter(getattr(object.c, "hid")==getattr(robject.c,\
 )).subquery()
```

results in column reference "hid" is ambiguous since both tables have hid column. 
How should I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for a subquery you typically want to name only those columns you need (since the subq isn't used to load full objects) and you then can use label() for anything additional:

```
subq = sess.query(object.a, object.b, object.hid.label('o_hid'), 
                  robject.c, robject.hid.label('r_hid')).filter(..).subquery()
```

the subquery then names those columns based on the label name:

```
   query(Something).join(subq, subq.c.o_hid == Something.q).filter(subq.c.r_hid == 5)
```

Comment: The label creates an alias but doesn't drop the original hid column. They still conflicts. I think we need a command like rename which renames the columns instead of alias.

Comment: In a query like `session.query(MyTable).join(MyTable.relation).filter_by(ambiguous_column='something')` SQL Alchemy 1.0.14 just arbitrarily took the `ambiguous_column` from the other side of the relation without any complaints. If I put the `join` after `filter_by` it takes from the first table, i.e., `MyTable`! Is this a bug or a feature?!?!

Comment: that's a [feature](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=filter_by#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by).  "The keyword expressions are extracted from the primary entity of the query, or the last entity that was the target of a call to Query.join()."

Comment: the Query should prefix all the column names with the table name if you are loading entities. if you're loading columns, label them explicitly.  It depends on what you're doing.